# Type inference based on calling location

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I want to create a wrapper function for a generic class like so:

```
public class ColumnData
{
    public static ColumnData<T> Create<T>(string name, int width, ColumnType type,
                                          Func<T, string> dataFormater)
    {
        return new ColumnData<T>(name, width, type, dataFormater);
    }
}
```

The `Create` method will be called as an argument to another function with a signature:

```
public void populateFromData<TDATA>(IEnumerable<TDATA> data, 
                                    params ColumnData<TDATA>[] columns)   
{
   ...
}
```

The intent here is to be able to do:

```
var myData = new List<MyDataType>();
dataListView.populateFromData(
    myData,
    ColumnData.Create("ID", 40, ColumnType.Numeric, x => x.ID.ToString());
```

However, `Create` can't infer the correct type for itself based on the signature it's expected to have, and thus the lambda doesn't know itself either.

Is this a limitation of type inference, or is there a way to make this setup work?

*Note: I'm willing to specify the actual data type somewhere in this function call, if necessary, but I **don't** want to specify it for each `.Create()`.*

Comment: I think this _is_ a limitation - `myData` tells you that `populateFromData`'s generic type is `<MyDataType>`, but that doesn't _force_ a generic type on `ColumnData.Create`; rather `ColumnData.Create` is responsible for its _own_ generic type, and _then_ the compiler checks to see if there's a `populateFromData` overload that matches. That's not to say there isn't a way to achieve what you want some other way, though...

Comment: Couldn't you provide the type parameter through ˜dataListView˜

Comment: @Rawling - That makes a lot of sense.  Any suggestions as to another way?

Comment: @Jani - No, because `dataListView` is a designer object (it inherits from ListView), so it can't be generic.  I could explicitly specify the type on the `populateFromData()` call, but that doesn't make any difference.

Comment: This is a similar question asked by myself  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477636/why-must-i-provide-explicitly-generic-parameter-types-while-the-compiler-should which refer to generic implementation limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have explained, it's not possible with the exact syntax you want. As a workaround, you could possibly move the typing to a separate building class:

```
    public class ColumnDataBuilder
    {
        public static ColumnDataBuilder<T> ColumnsFor<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            return new ColumnDataBuilder<T>(data);
        }
    }

    public class ColumnDataBuilder<T> : ColumnDataBuilder
    {
        public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; private set; }

        public ColumnDataBuilder(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            this.Data = data;
        }
        public ColumnData<T> Create(string name, int width, ColumnType type, Func<T, string> dataFormater)
        {
            return new ColumnData<T>(name, width, type, dataFormater);
        }

        public void populateFromData(params ColumnData<T>[] columns)
        {
            ///...
        }
    }

    public class ColumnData<T>
    {
        public ColumnData(string name, int width, ColumnType type, Func<T, string> dataFormatter)
        {

        }
    }
```

Then usage might look like:

```
        var builder = ColumnDataBuilder.ColumnsFor(new List<MyDataType>());
        builder.populateFromData(builder.Create("ID", 40, ColumnType.Numeric, x => x.ID.ToString()));
        IEnumerable<MyDataType> data = builder.Data;
```

Or closer to your example usage (if you want to keep `populateFromData` on your `dataListView`) in which case you can ditch the `ColumnDataBuilder<T>.populateFromData` method (since it seems from your comments that's not possible to keep there):

```
        var myData = new List<MyDataType>();
        var builder = ColumnDataBuilder.ColumnsFor(myData);
        dataListView.populateFromData(myData, builder.Create("ID", 40, ColumnType.Numeric, x => x.ID.ToString()));
```

Or a bit of best of both worlds:

```
        var builder = ColumnDataBuilder.ColumnsFor(new List<MyDataType>());
        dataListView.populateFromData(builder.Data, builder.Create("ID", 40, ColumnType.Numeric, x => x.ID.ToString()));
```

EDIT: Considering your comments, you probably don't want `populateFromData` or possibly even the `IEnumerable<T> Data` stored on the `ColumnDataBuilder`, so you might simplify to have this instead:

```
    public class ColumnDataBuilder<T> : ColumnDataBuilder
    {
        public ColumnData<T> Create(string name, int width, ColumnType type, Func<T, string> dataFormater)
        {
            return new ColumnData<T>(name, width, type, dataFormater);
        }
    }

    public class ColumnDataBuilder
    {
        public static ColumnDataBuilder<T> ColumnsFor<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
        {
            return new ColumnDataBuilder<T>();
        }
    }
```

With the usage from above:

```
        var myData = new List<MyDataType>();
        var builder = ColumnDataBuilder.ColumnsFor(myData);
        dataListView.populateFromData(myData, builder.Create("ID", 40, ColumnType.Numeric, x => x.ID.ToString()));
```

Comment: Oooh, that's really clever.  I just posted my own answer, but I think I'll switch to this, since it's more generically useful and doesn't involve remembering to alias (and what the alias means).

Comment: Given the last usage scenario, I was able to boil this down even further.  I moved `ColumnsFor<T>` to the class for `dataListView`, and kept the `ColumnDataBuilder<T>` class, but removed everything except the `Create` function.  The rest was extraneous.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you just have to specify the generic type parameter explicitly, when c# cannot infer it's actual type.

```
dataListView.populateFromData(
    myData,
    ColumnData.Create<MyDataType>("ID", 40, ColumnType.Numeric, x => x.ID.ToString());
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  When the datatype is something like `ShippingReceiptHeader.PendingLineItemDetails`, it gets rather painful.

Answer (score 0):

One answer I just came up with involves an alias.  I removed the wrapper class and moved the `Create` method into the `ColumnData<T>` class directly, then added:

```
using ColumnData = ColumnData<MyDataType>;
```

This allows me to access `ColumnData.Create()` with the type hint to the compiler, without needing to specify it on each line.  I'll need to create the alias in each file where I want to use this, but it is a workable solution.

Comment: I think I might lose my marbles managing the resulting code, but if it works for you, all the more power to you!

Comment: And that's exactly why I went with your answer instead. :)